# How to call Spring @Service constructor each time the object is used?

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a Spring @Service class, which has a constructor that puts some Strings in a Hashtable. The first time I use the service, it works perfectly, but after that the constructor is never called again, so next time I use the service the hashtable is empty.

Therefore, is there any annotation to force Spring executing the constructor always?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your class and show us how you intend to use it.

Comment: You don´t need more info, it´s clearly explained in the description

Comment: Do you empty the hashtable every time you "use" it?

Comment: I never said that, you are inventing it. I said "next time I use the service the hashtable is empty".

Comment: I'm trying to understand. I can only guess until you explain. What makes it empty?

Comment: @stackpepe you should really consider showing your code or thinned down version of it for the community to be able to assist you effectively. As Sotirios explained we have to guess now how you are using it, and the answer can change depending on the assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your @Service is default scoped ie Singleton then what you are seeing is expected. To call constructor every time the class is referenced in other beans , you have to add @Scope("prototype").

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to try it, but, should I put the @Scope annotation on the class or in the constructor?

Comment: It should be on class